# How can I keep two Winforms labels centrally aligned?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, text-alignment

I'm trying to keep two labels centrally aligned, one above the other. Before the form runs, everything looks great, but when running they are all misaligned.

**Before running:**
[image]

**After running:**
[image]

**Example code for one label:**

```
Me.TemperatureLabel1.AutoSize = True
Me.TemperatureLabel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke
Me.TemperatureLabel1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Bahnschrift", 25.0!)
Me.TemperatureLabel1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray
Me.TemperatureLabel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(278, 53)
Me.TemperatureLabel1.Name = "TemperatureLabel1"
Me.TemperatureLabel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(227, 41)
Me.TemperatureLabel1.TabIndex = 8
Me.TemperatureLabel1.Text = "TempLabelVal"
Me.TemperatureLabel1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
Me.TemperatureLabel1.Visible = False
```

So what I would like is to have the values populated, but centrally aligned above each other.

Comment: did you set `AutoSize = false` on the labels?

Comment: @Fixation if I set ```AutoSize = false``` the text inside it get clipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set label's AutoSize property to false and TextAlign property to MiddleCenter.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. What also helped was to put actual representative text in the labels so I could size them in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

As another option, you can use `TableLayoutPanel` having 4 columns and 2 rows. Then drop labels inside cells, set `Anchor` property of the `Label` controls to none and keep their `AutoSize` as `true`.

This way, the labels are always will be aligned in center of the cell.

It also allows you to have absolute, percent or auto-size mode for columns.